# Randomly (with weight bias) select row from database?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: Select Random Entry, but Weight Towards Certain Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417621/mysql-select-random-entry-but-weight-towards-certain-entries)

I have a table that I would like to be able to randomly select a user from, but in this table I have an 'Entries' column. I have been able to randomly select a user, but now I am trying to take into account their number of entries (higher the number, the more likely they are to win). How would I go about doing this?

My table looks something like:

```
FN   | LN    | ENTRIES
Bob  | Smith | 20
John | Doe   | 3
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it isnt really random if someone has more of a chance to be selected.

Comment: [Check this thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716163/select-random-row-from-mysql-with-probability

Comment: @Hunter: it is. it's just not uniformly distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To weight them, multiply rand()  by the entries column..

```
select * from table order by entries*rand() desc limit 1;
```

Comment: It's worth saying that this is very slow for big tables, as it has to generate a random number for every row of the table.

Comment: @vincent It won't work by itself if the developer wants to weight them by the value of the entries column in the table.

Comment: Yes, I misread the question and edited my previous comment.

Comment: I think I am having troubles getting it to work. I have inserted 2 rows, one has 2 entries while the other has 300 entries. I has picked the one with fewer entries more often than the other one.

Comment: @user790068: it is to be expected. Lower values will be selected before higher in ascending order. You need to add `DESC` keyword after `entries*rand()`

Comment: @user Are you saying you want to randomize on the number of rows in the table?

Comment: This gives a horribly skewed distribution.. say there are 98 rows weighted 1 and 1 row weighted 2. RAND() will produce a number between 0 and 1, so 50% of the time the number will be > 0.5. For the row weighted 2, (RAND() * 2) will be greater than 1 50% of the time. This is larger than all (RAND() * 1) results, so the row weighted 2 will be selected at least 50% of the time. It should in fact be selected 2% of the time (2/100).